# Display a ProgressBar when I perform a query

Tags: delphi

To display a ProgressBar when I perform a query, I use this code:

```
if not Query1.Prepared then
  Query1.Prepare;
Query1.Open;

ProgressBar1.Max := Query1.RecordCount;

ProgressBar1.Min := 0;
ProgressBar1.Position := 0;
Query1.First;
while not Query1.Eof do
begin
  ProgressBar1.Position := ProgressBar1.Position+1;
  ProgressBar1.StepIt;           
  Query1.Next;
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;
```

But the display of the ProgressBar remains frozen (I do not see the progress of the ProgressBar).

How do I view the progress of ProgressBar1 when I perform this query?

Comment: Do not use `Position+1` and `StepIt()` together. You are incrementing the progress too much. Use one or the other, not both. And don't use `Application ProcessMessages()` at all. Either use the Form's `Update()` method, or move the query to another thread.

Comment: thank you Remy ,
I deleted :

Application ProcessMessages () and StepIt ().
I added Update () method but the display is still frozen.

`While not Query1.Eof do
Beginners
   ProgressBar1.Position: = ProgressBar1.Position + 1;
   ProgressBar1.Update ();
   Query1.Next;
End;`
Did I make a mistake in this code please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't running progress on the query. The query happens at the call to `Open`. That's when the query is sent to the database which in turn processes it, taking time.

Your attempt to perform progress happens later, once the query is complete and you iterate over the results. That is probably so quick that progress is needless. In any case, if it was time consuming, at least it's happening in your code and so you can show progress.

The real problem you have is that the query happens elsewhere, on the database server, and you don't get progress callbacks from it. I'm sure some database servers do offer progress callbacks but I don't think your technology has that available.

Perhaps the simplest thing for you to do is as follows:

1. Move the query code into a separate thread. This is essential in order to keep the main UI thread responsive.
2. Instead of attempting to fill a progress bar, which you can't do because you don't have progress callbacks, use a marquee progress bar instead. This is the progress bar that moves back and forth to tell the user that the program is busy, but not hung.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I use Absolute Database locally. So the database is in my pc.
I totally agree with you on what you said.
To move the query code into a separate thread. I've got no ideas how to do this in my case. i wille search an example
An example would be appreciated.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you. However, the GUI thread is blocked while the query is running, so the Marquee progress bar doesn't work :)

Comment: @DaveBoltman Well, that's entirely to be expected, because you blocked the main thread. If you wish to show a marquee progress bar then you'd need to do that on a worker thread. Which is tricky in Delphi because the UI libraries must be accessed from the main thread. If you are targeting Windows you could create a pure Win32 window and run that out of a background thread. Your real problem is that you made a mistake in blocking the main thread in the first place.

Comment: Sure, thank you. Looking into executing the query asynchronously now...

Answer (score 0):

Some database components provide asynchronous operation like the TADOxxx components, This way you can show progress while the query is running. Here's a complete example how to use aysnc mode (This example uses SQL server):

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Data.DB, Data.Win.ADODB, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TDataSetWrapper = class(TDataSet);

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ADOConnection1: TADOConnection;
    ADOQuery1: TADOQuery;
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    AbortQuery : Boolean;
    procedure ADOQuery1FetchProgress(DataSet: TCustomADODataSet; Progress, MaxProgress: Integer; var EventStatus: TEventStatus);
    procedure ADOQuery1FetchComplete(DataSet: TCustomADODataSet; const Error: Error; var EventStatus: TEventStatus);
    procedure ProcessRecords;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

// warning about OnFetchxxxx events, they occurr OUTSIDE the main thread, always synchronize!!!
procedure TForm1.ADOQuery1FetchComplete(DataSet: TCustomADODataSet; const Error: Error; var EventStatus: TEventStatus);

begin
 if EventStatus = esOK then
  // access your records here
  TThread.Synchronize(nil, ProcessRecords);
 TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure()
  begin
   Button1.Caption := 'Start';
   Button1.Tag := 0;
  end
 );
end;

procedure TForm1.ADOQuery1FetchProgress(DataSet: TCustomADODataSet; Progress, MaxProgress: Integer; var EventStatus: TEventStatus);
begin
 // query has been aborted
 if Button1.Tag=2 then
  begin
   EventStatus := esCancel;
   TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure()
    begin
     if Assigned(ADOQuery1.RecordSet) then ADOQuery1.RecordSet.Cancel;
     Button1.Tag := 0;
    end
   );
  end else
 // query busy
 if Button1.Tag=1 then
  TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure()
   begin
    // indicate progress 
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('progress: %d',[Progress]));
   end
  );
end;

procedure TForm1.ProcessRecords;
begin
   ADOQuery1.First;
   Memo1.Lines.Add(ADOQuery1.Fields[0].AsString);
   ADOQuery1.Next;
   Memo1.Lines.Add(ADOQuery1.Fields[0].AsString);
   ADOQuery1.Next;
   Memo1.Lines.Add(ADOQuery1.Fields[0].AsString);
   ADOQuery1.Next;
   Memo1.Lines.Add(ADOQuery1.Fields[0].AsString);
   ADOQuery1.Next;
   Memo1.Lines.Add(ADOQuery1.Fields[0].AsString);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 // use tag to define state we are in
 // 0 means idle
 // 1 means query active
 // 2 means abort query
 if Button1.Tag = 0 then
  begin
   Button1.Tag := 1;
   // simulate long query with cross join, make sure your table has enough records (in this case 1000 records is enough)
   ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT TOP 100000 T1.* FROM MyTable T1, MyTable T2';
   ADOQuery1.Open;
   Button1.Caption := 'Abort';
  end else
 if Button1.Tag = 1 then
  begin
   // abort!!!
   Button1.Tag := 2;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Button1.Caption := 'Start';
 Button1.Tag := 0;
 ADOQuery1.ExecuteOptions := [eoAsyncExecute, eoAsyncFetchNonBlocking];
 ADOQuery1.OnFetchProgress := ADOQuery1FetchProgress;
 ADOQuery1.OnFetchComplete := ADOQuery1FetchComplete;
 ADOConnection1.Connected := True;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Button tags? Surely we can do better.

Comment: @ whosrdaddy thank you.In my case, the FetchComplete property is not available in my Query unfortunately.

Comment: @Bill, Absolute Database has an ODBC driver. Pretty much everything that runs ODBC can be used with the TADOxxx components. It is up to the ODBC driver to support asynchronous operation or not...